# Add same block to one page but different data

Tags: blocks

I have one block on the page :

```
<block type="obishomeaddon/customcategory" name="customcategory"   template="homeaddon/customcategory.phtml">
    <action method="setData"> <name>column_count</name> <value>4</value> </action>
    <action method="setData"> <name>category_id</name> <value>213</value> </action>
</block>
```

Now, I want to have two of these blocks but different `category_id`. The problem I have is Magento will loop through the XML first, so the last `category_id` will be set and all the blocks will have the same `category_id`

Which is a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you gave your blocks different names?

Comment: yep, different names - different blocks

Comment: thanks you guys. This is a stupid question, I didn't notice the name was the same :)

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure your blocks have different names.